# How to restore an object in Silverlight 5

Tags: aop, silverlight-5.0, loose-coupling

I have created an application by using Silverlight 5. There are many two-way databind in it. I want to retore a change in UI by restoring the object behind. For example:

I have an object behind which contains properties double Left, Right, I inherited it from INotifyPropertyChanged. In UI, I created tow button (ButtonLeft and ButtonRight) and their parent a Canvas Control, ButtonLeft bind Left property in two-way mode and ButtonRight bind Right property in two-way mode. It works very well, if I drag ButtonLeft, then the Left property will be updated with the new Left Value, same for ButtonRight.

Is there any way to restore the old value after the change of UI. Actually, the relation of class in my application is very complicated, I have already knew that retore the value of property in object will restore the UI, so is there any way (more general and loose-coupling) to restore all the objects that need to be restored.

I have thought of creating an interface IRestorable (inside Store(), Restore()) for objects that need to save and restore state. An attribute Restorable for property which need to be restored. For me, the use of AOP could be a good idea, each time when an instance of IRestorable is created, AOP will call a method for saving the current state (properties which is marked an [Restorable]) of object. I don't know if I was on the right way. If not, any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of memeno design pattern.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18025/Generic-Memento-Pattern-for-Undo-Redo-in-C